# List results based on whether they have a certain property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here are two kind of responses when I list all the users in my db.

```
{
_id: "5bcf4f4d48a3067897c22344",
__v: 0
},
{
_id: "5bcf507b65f77778ab23b53f",
firstname: "major",
lastname: "general",
__v: 0
}
```

As you can see, there is an entry without firstname and lastname prop. At this point, I'm trying to clean up the db and remove all the ones that don't have firstname or lastname property. Here's what I have.

```
async deleteUsersWithoutNames() {
    const usersWithNoName = await this.userModel.find()
        .where((response: any) => response.hasOwnProperty('firstname')).equals(false);
    return usersWithNoName;
  }
```

This doesn't work and express screams that the `path must be a string or object`.

This is the userModel initialization.

```
  private userModel = new UserEntity().getModelForClass(UserEntity);
```

UserEntity class extends `Typegoose` by [Typegoose](https://github.com/szokodiakos/typegoose).

How do I go on about doing this?

Comment: Can we see the full method calling `deleteUsersWithoutNames` since this does not explain why express is throwing an error.

Comment: also correct me if I'm wrong but i don't think you can use `.where()` after `find()` since you could use `where()` for a query itself and it will send another request to the database (no reason too). I believe you should have `const users = await this.userModel.find()` followed by `const usersWithNoName = users.filter(user => user.hasOwnProperty('firstname').equals(false));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now that I think about it a better way to solve your query

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

```
async deleteUsersWithoutNames() {
    return await this.userModel.where({firstname: {$exists:false}})       
}
```